# Display JSON response text from ajax in jQuery Template

Tags: django, jquery, jquery-templates

I need to pass the response from ajax call to a jquery template.The response json is not malformed.I have checked this by using alert statements in the ajax fn.When the response is passed to the template,it does not get recognized.For example,when I use ${field1} in template,nothing gets displayed in the browser.No error messages are displayed at the browser.Can someone help me fix this issue?

Json response from server:

```
    { 
        "field1": 23432434, 
        "field2": "sometext",
    }
```

Ajax fn:

```
    function getinfo(uri)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
        url:    'http://{{request.META.SERVER_NAME}}'+uri,
        success: function(info) {
                  return info;
              },
        async:   false,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
     }
```

Template:

```
    <script id="infoTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
            <div>${field1}</div>
   </script>
```

Code to Bind JSON to template:

```
<script id="Template1" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">      
      {{tmpl(getinfo(uri)) "#infoTemplate"}} 
</script>
```

Note: I can't use the following method to bind JSON with template.That's a long story.

```
function getinfo(uri)
{
    $.getJSON('http://{{request.META.SERVER_NAME}}'+uri, function(data) {
         $("#infoTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#somedivid");
   });
}
```

Comment: Try using jsonp as the DataType.

Comment: @citizen conn - no luck!

Comment: BTW, you have lots of questions that have answers not accepted. You should fix that, or other users might not want to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how callbacks work. You're returning `info` to the callback function, and not to `getinfo`.

You either have to do something like you proposed after, or keep the result from the ajax call in a global var and call the tmpl function after while, to be sure that you have already got the answer from the ajax call. The first way is the way to go.

Comment: I intend to return info(a JSON object) and pass it as an argument to {{tmpl}}.I'm not sure if this is the right way to approach.For now,I have opted for the method I have mentioned in my "Note".It would be of great help if you can explain why the previous method wont work.

Comment: The previous won't work because your "getinfo" isn't returning anything. When you do "return info;" on "success", you're returning "info" to the callback func, that's called by jQuery and throw away, and not to the "getinfo" function. Let me know if I was able to be clearer this time.